# Freeform forms fieldtype

Tags: plugin-freeform, freeform

I see there is a freeform forms fieldtype available after the plugin was installed. What exactly does this field do and how to render it correctly (within matrix)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Freeform docs](http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v1/overview/fieldtype.html#how-the-fieldtypes-work):

> The Freeform Form (or Submissions) fieldtype lets the user assign any
>   Freeform form (or form submissions) to any element: a section entry,
>   categories, assets, etc.

In a nutshell, this means you can embed forms to any entries you have, like so:

[image: Embed freeform]

[This section](http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v1/overview/fieldtype.html#usage-in-templates) within the docs shows you how to correctly code your templates.